# Create JSON object from PHP MySQL result

Tags: php, mysql, json

I want to create a JSON object from my MySQL results with PHP so I can pass it to JavaScript. I don't quite understand the difference between JSON array and JSON object.

This is how I do it. But is there a better way? This is the array way I believe?

```
$json = array();
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
  $json['firstname'] = $r['firstname'];
  $json['lastname'] = $r['lastname'];
}
echo json_encode($json);
```

I want to be able to get the info from JavaScript, by selecting all first names only If I wish etc..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can try this, fetch data and push to array, then echo that array

```
$info=array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
array_push($info,$row);
}
echo json_encode($info);
```

would return

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["firstname"]=> string(3) "foo" ["lastname"]=> string(3) "bar" } [1]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["firstname"]=> string(3) "foo" ["lastname"]=> string(3) "bar" } }
```

json

```
[{"id":"1","firstname":"foo","lastname":"bar"},{"id":"2","firstname":"foo","lastname":"bar"}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Well this would encode every row, with each row being the JSON Object:

```
$json = array();
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
  $json[] = $r;
}
echo json_encode($json);
```